# Add Task dependency to existing Plugin Task in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

I include a second gradle file `my.gradle` in my `build.gradle` file.

The content of `my.gradle` is:

apply plugin: MyPlugin

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
       project.tasks.create(name: "myTask", type: MyTaskClass) {
       }
    }
}
```

In my `build.gradle` I set at the top:

```
apply from: 'myPlugin.gradle'
```

Now I want to set a task dependency in `build.gradle` with:

```
tasks.myPlugin.myTask.dependsOn += someOtherTask
```

When I build I get the following error:

```
> Could not find property 'myPlugin' on task set.
```

How can I access `myTask` from `myPlugin` in `build.gradle`?

Edit: I tried to make sure that someTask runs after myTask. I tried to do this with:

```
taskX.finalizedBy taskY
```

in my case:

```
tasks.myPlugin.myTask.finalizedBy someOtherTask
```

but the former does not work.

Comment: Is that psuedo code? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Yes, this is easy to do in `Gradle`, you have the right syntax. What is the issue? Do you have a `build.gradle` file to show?

Comment: you seem to be using dependsOn in reverse. if A should run before B, in task B definition you should say task B - dependson A see: https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:adding_dependencies_to_tasks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script will do the job:

**my.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: MyPlugin

class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
       project.tasks.create(name: "myTask", type: Copy) {
       }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply from: 'my.gradle'

task someOtherTask << {
   println 'doLast'
}

project.tasks.myTask.dependsOn(someOtherTask)
```

Comment: I have similar request as the above but with the difference of wanting to make sure that my task I am created is depending on the task defined in the plugin, any idea how this can be done?

Comment: @MiguelCosta I don't quite understand what is you scenario.

Comment: nevermind, your example was perfect I was just calling my task with uppercase instead of lowercase and it was not finding it. but is basically the same as this but I want to ensure my task is only executed after a task coming from a plugin is executed

Answer (score -2):

If you include your plugin correctly, you should see your task.  For example, if you include java plugin and run

gradle tasks --all

You should see compileJava included.  Same for yours, run `gradle tasks --all`.  You should be able to reference it as tasks.myTask or tasks['myTask']